# Where will my question regarding web hosting go?

Tags: support, web-hosting

My guess is super user, but I didn't get many responses there.

I could have asked it in Stack Overflow, but guessed I could ask first.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, abel!  Thanks for dropping by to ask instead of just posting randomly -- many people don't bother.  +1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best try could be :

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

**Site definition**

> Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for professional and enthusiast webmasters. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, traffic is a problem at webmasters.stackexchange.com, otherwise it is the right place for my question.

Comment: Traffic isn't much of a problem, it's just that webmastering has a rather small audience compared to "Cooking", "Gaming" or "Web Apps". There are professional webmaster that can give you good answer to your question and that's what mater.

Comment: Very true.i already have some responses http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/investigating-and-finding-a-web-host