# Where should web hosting platform questions go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Related question: *[Where will my question regarding web hosting go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61390/where-will-my-question-regarding-web-hosting-go)*

I just asked a question about [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com, but I then realized a better place to post it would be http://serverfault.com, so I moved the question. Then I saw some similar questions on http://stackoverflow.com that had in one case *hundreds* of upvotes. Some questions are programming related, and some are about the hosting platform.

It seems to me that the place for actual back-end / platform problems and discussions is Server Fault, but unfortunately people seem to jump to Stack Overflow first (even Heroku's documentation, for example, tells you to ask at Stack Overflow for platform-related questions).

I dig that this is kind of a murky meta question, because hosting questions can cross over into the territory of all 3 sites. If I were being selfish, I'd just ask at Stack Overflow since it would probably get more eyes. **Should we be more proactive about migrating questions like these to the appropriate sites?**

Comment: I just read on ServerFault that questions should not be about "Anything in a development environment". That makes things a bit less clear.

Comment: It depends on the question, since Heroku involves all three.  If it's a question about resolving a development question using code on heroku, use stackoverflow. If it's a question about the web site UI, dealing with stats, etc, go for webmasters.  If it's about integrating heroku into your production server environment, go for serverfault. I don't think we need to be *more* proactive about moving, though, we already do move those that are clearly outside one expert's domain.  If it otherwise fits well enough and doesn't ruffle feathers, leave it.

Comment: Cool, that sounds pretty clear to me.